# Why do I get mail notifications I do not see on the site afterwards?

Tags: discussion

I asked [a great question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952748/how-to-deal-with-numerous-elements-in-a-condition) today and quickly got an even greater answer. Since [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) was very quick commenting, then turning the answer into a question, I saw the answer popping up on the site, tested the solution, commented back and accepted the answer.

I later saw in my email a thread *"6 new items in your Stack Exchange inbox"* which had some of the comments/answers (marked with "OK" below) but also some others (comments & answer) which I do not see on the site (marked with a "?"):

[image]

I assume that they were "technical comments" ("your comment is great, pls move it as an answer", "done") deleted afterwards, or an answer someone removed in the meantime.

1. Is this common practice to "clean up" after oneself following such an exchange (I never did it before, even though I engaged in a similar conversation regarding some of the comments which were actual answers)
2. Is there a place where I can see the modifications in my question? (I saw that this is possible when there is an explicit "modified by JohnDoe" icon down the question, but I do not see a "history" link anywhere on the page)

Comment: How humble you are :)

Comment: Glad you noticed. I was afraid that my groundbreaking question which revolutionizes Python would pass unnoticed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that those comments were deleted.

1. User posted a comment
2. You got a notification
3. User deleted the comment
4. You don't see deleted comments on the site
5. Done

> Is this common practice to "clean up" after oneself following such an exchange

Yes, if the comments aren't needed/relevant anymore then they should be deleted to clean up the post and make it more valuable. Ex. User posts answer as comment --> Someone asks in a comment to make that an answer --> User does so --> Relevant comments can now be deleted.

Another example: You comment on a post and ask the author to add details/logs/etc... to their post --> they do --> Your comment is no longer relevant so it can/should be deleted to clean up the comments section.

> Is there a place where I can see the modifications in my question?

If the post has been edited then you will see "edited by someUser". You can click on that and see the edit history. I guess that's what you're asking.

You won't have an edit history if it is within the grace period (5 mins. I believe). If you are talking about seeing the deleted comments then no this is not possible.

Comment: Yes, this is what I guessed and mentioned in my question. Thus my questions 1. and 2. :)

Comment: Yes, sorry. Got a little quick. I have edited to answer your questions.